# Performing operations on all members of a GroupBy object

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

After using `.groupby` is it possible to perform operations on all of groups in the `groupby` object as a whole, similar to the behaviour when it was a `dataframe`. Or do I always need to keep a non-grouped copy?

```
test = df
test_group = test.groupby(test.index.month)
print test_group['A'].median()
print test['A'].median()
print type(test_group), type(test)

1     10.60
2     10.40
3      8.70
4     14.15
5     15.80
6     13.20
7     16.15
8     20.70
9     17.90
10    15.45
11    13.25
12    11.30
Name: test, dtype: float64
14.0
<class 'pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: You can just call `test_group.median()` no?

Comment: No, calling `.median` on the `.groupby` object returns the median for each group (in my case there are 12 groups). The output looks at the same as my example except they'd 12 values for each column in the `.groupby` object.
Calling `.median()` on the original `dataframe` returns a single value (the 14.0 in the example). 
At the moment I keep an ungrouped copy of and `.groupby` objects, I was wondering if there was a way I could avoid doing this.

Comment: I'm confused about this output.  Wouldn't the output from `print test_group['A'].median()` be the first output you listed and not `14.0` ?

Comment: Apologies, my mistake- I've corrected the code now. The first output was from the grouped object and the second from the dataframe.

Comment: Did we decide this was a transform?

Comment: @AndyHayden Yes, `.transform()` was what I'd needed.